# Removing extensions with .htaccess on Drupal site

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, drupal-7

How do you use .htaccess to remove extensions.  On the website, I want old links to work, but, site layout has changed.  I want to map

/arithmetic/whole_numbers/practice/whole_number_rounding.html

to rediredt(mapped) to

/arithmetic/whole_numbers/practice/whole_number_rounding

I have moved from a standard html site to a Drupal site and the new page names have been defined to look like the original pages names, except the lack of .html extensions.

Answer (score 0):

I know it doesn't answer your question directly but what about this:
http://drupal.org/project/path_redirect

**Edited**: if it's not enough try this:
drupal.org/documentation/modules/path

Comment: Thank you, I am using that module to create redirects to go from format node/1 to format /something/something.   My goal is to get rid of extension.

Comment: right: I wouldn't play directly with htaccess in drupal as Drupal itself should play nicely with clean urls... especially when you install path module : http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/path

Comment: Thank you, I will consider simply adding the .html extension back on the path name, it is permited in Drupals path module, it is simply something I am attempting to avoid ... for potentially no valid reason.